# Webpack: 'Require is not defined' after adding React to Bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I've used Webpack to bundle all my npm modules. Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
        ]
    },
};
```

Here's the main.js I refer to. As you can see, I try to import React, React-dom, fixed-data-table, chartjs, jquery and visjs.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import vis from 'vis';
```

All is good, and I remove the react, chartjs, jquery etc. src from my index.html and just refer to the newly created bundle.js altogether:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "vis": "^4.17.0"
  }
}
```

In my main .js file with front-end functionalities such as React classes, I now add:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
import vis from 'vis';
```

it correctly acknowledges the `React` function which is great. However, when I open the index.html, at line 1(where I import react), it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at n.run (babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:6:14)
    at Function.n.run (babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3)
    at l (babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3)
    at babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
n.run @ babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3
l @ babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3
s.onreadystatechange @ babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3
```

I don't understand why require is not translated as I used `babel-loader` to translate it to be understood by the browser.

Did I do something wrong in the process here? Webpack has a steep learning curve I've found - so it might very well be a rookie mistake by myself somewhere.

Comment: This is strange, the error stack points to `babel.5.8.38.browser.min.js:3`, you got Babel in you page too?